# Python for loop and arrays

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to python. I'm trying to learn data extracting from an Excel file. I encountered the following statement:

```
sheet_data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
```

I understand regular for loops, but not the below version:

```
x for y in range()
```

What does it mean when you have a variable **x** before the **for y in range()**?

Comment: This is called list comprehension if you want to google it.

Comment: `x for y in range` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @preezzzy I found it. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: That should get you rolling.
@cricket_007 is right about the the invalid syntax by the way.

Comment: @cricket_007 Right. I wasn't sure what to call it before, but now I know.

Answer (score 1):

The **for** statement is used for looping over a list. This is referred to as an **iterator**. When it is encompassed by [..], this is referred to as a list comprehension.

List comprehensions allow you to transform one list into another. This is sometimes referred to as a mapping i.e. mapping from X -> Y where a function transforms the value of X into the returned value of Y

So, for example, in

```
[y + 2 for y in range(...)]
```

the **for** is iterating over all values in the list produced by the range(). Each list element has 2 added to each value of y, so the final result is a list where each element is 2 greater than the corresponding element in the source list. Thus, range(3) would produce [0, 1, 2] which then transforms into [2, 3, 4].

So [y for y in range(..)] wouldn't actually accomplish much.

I see that in the example you have provided there are two iterators, which complicates things a bit. But essentially, they are providing two reference variables: **r** and **col**, from which the final result is derived using these two variables.

List comprehensions are a very powerful tool in Python. Definitely worth knowing.

Comment: Pedantic: "List comprehensions allow you to transform one _iterable_ into a new `list`." `range` itself isn't even a `list` in Py3 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

These are called list comprehensions in python.  If you have a function `do_something` then the following two blocks are equivalent:

```
result = [do_something(y) for y in range(10)]
```

...

```
result = []
for y in range(10):
    result.append(do_something(y))
```

Where `range(10)` could be any iterable.

Think of them as quick ways to create lists.  They work for dictionaries too as of python 2.7.  [This tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) may be helpful.

Comment: Where is `x` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The "x" is an arbitrary variable name that holds the values of the sequence object. Using it in a list comprehension or in a generator expression will return the items in the iterable object that is being stepped through.